# Does a java agent run in a separate thread?

Tags: java, jvm, multithreading, javaagents

I feel that this is something I should know, but does a java agent (specified with -javaagent) run in a separate thread? I've read that [a Java agent is a pluggable library that runs embedded in a JVM and intercepts the classloading process](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html), but I want to make sure: does it really *intercept* them (which sounds like it's running in another thread and monitoring class loads) or is it notified by the JVM (the JVM invokes it to resolve the class load; there isn't a separate thread for it)?

Again, I get the feeling that I should be able to figure it out, but be nice to me, I'm working too hard and my brain is kinda fried :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ClassFileTransformer gets invoked by the ClassLoader. A little modification of the transformer from the article you linked, to look like this:

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes)
        throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    new RuntimeException("Transformer to Transform Class: " + className)
            .printStackTrace(System.out);
    return bytes;
}
```

yields this output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Transformer to Transform Class: MyMain
    at com.javalobby.tnt.instrument.SimpleTransformer.transform(SimpleTransformer.java:14)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Very clever way to find out, btw :). Thanks for trying it out!